# How to make a responsive horizontal SVG line on a webpage?

Tags: html, css, svg

I don't fully understand how SVGs work yet. I know that viewBox have something to do with the scale of the SVG, and I have read that I shouldn't have specific height and width attributes when making a responsive SVG. I know there are a couple of questions about this here already, but as I don't understand them, I'm asking a bit more specific one.

I want to make a horizontal SVG line that changes length based on the width of the webpage.

I have been able to make a horizontal line with this code so far:

```
 <svg id="horisontalLinje" width="500" height="5">
       <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="500" y2="0"></line>
 </svg>
```

CSS:

```
#horisontalLinje {
    stroke: black;
    stroke-width: 1;
    
}
```

The problem is as said that this line isn't responsive. What I want is this line to get a lower "width" based on the percentage of the width of the website the SVG is on. Like when using "vw" as a size in CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. I just figured it out... Just had to change the "width" to "x vw" and the "x2" to the same as the width.

Comment: If you are not deleting the question, it could be a good idea to answer with an example that spells out the solution, so that others can learn from it.

Comment: You could have used a viewBox attribute (like viewBox="0 0 500 5") and no width and height . Please read about [viewBox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox). Also it would have been a better idea to use a bigger value for the y1 and y2 attributes like 2.5. Otherwise half of the stroke would fall outside the svg canvas

Answer (score 1):

Even thought I really like working with SVG, sometimes a simple solution can also do the job. I this example I styled a `<hr>` -- a [horizontal rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/hr). It is mush easier to work with in this case.

```css
hr {
  background: black;
  height: 2px;
  position: relative;
}

hr:before {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: black;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: -2px;
  top: -4px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

hr:after {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: black;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: -2px;
  top: -4px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:100%">
  <hr/>
</div>

<div style="width:66%">
  <hr/>
</div>

<div style="width:33%">
  <hr/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `vw` approach will work, unless someone is using a very old browser.  Another, more traditional way is to use a `viewBox`.

```css
#horisontalLinje {
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 1;
}
```

```html
<svg id="horisontalLinje" width="100%" height="1" viewBox="0 0 10 1" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <line x1="0" y1="0.5" x2="100" y2="0.5"></line>
</svg>
```

One other problem with your SVG is that the `y` coordinates are 0.  This means that half the line is off the top of the SVG viewport.  The top (off-screen) half of the line is from -0.5 < y < 0, and the visible half is from 0 < y < 0.5.  In other words, despite setting `stroke-width` to 1. You are effectively only seeing a stroke of 0.5.  You can fix that by setting the `y` coordinates to 0.5.